# Creating an email address if it doesn't exist in my domain

Tags: email, email-validation

I am in the process of trying to host an email server or find somewhere to host it. There is one catch though: if my domain is test.com and someone sends an email to bob@test.com, say this email address doesn't exist, I want to be able to create bob@test.com and basically make it so that whoever sent that email never knows that bob@test.com didn't exist at the time of sending the email.

I am inexperienced with email and am unable to find really anything about this. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33509943/how-to-send-e-mail-from-non-existing-autogenerated-unique-id-email), but the wording seems like a different problem. Is this idea possible at all? Even if it is possible, are there laws that restrict this?

Thanks for your help